# Image broke while displaying with lightning aura components

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Images are displaying as broken with lightning aura components. Below is the code.

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!orderDtl.ProdImg}">
  <img src="{!orderDtl.ProdImg}"/>
</aura:if>
```

{!orderDtl.ProdImg} is a opensource image url.

can someone help in solving this.

Comment: What do you mean by broken? What is the expected outcome? Can you add a screenshot by [editing](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/289829/edit) your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing too much about how exactly this is failing, just by looking at it, you are referencing an attribute called "orderDtl", but aren't using the correct syntax.  Please try this:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.orderDtl.ProdImg}">
  <img src="{!v.orderDtl.ProdImg}"/>
</aura:if>
```

Solution: Make sure you are adding the `{!v.}` to your attribute references.